# Table-valued function that takes table as parameter and performs join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I use SQL server 2016.
I want to write a function that takes a table as a parameter and then performs a join on that table with another table.
I have declared the following type:

```
CREATE TYPE WorklistTable AS TABLE (WorklistId int NOT NULL)
```

Then I use it in a lot of functions that do selects based on certain conditions

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetSomeData] (
@WorklistIds WorklistTable readonly
)
RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN
    (   
    select WorklistId, wlu.UserId
    from @WorklistIds
    join [dbo].[WorklistUser] wlu on wlu.WorklistId = @WorklistIds.worklistId   
    -- the rest is omitted 
);
```

I get the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@WorklistIds".

I tried to declare the variable, but I got an error:

> The variable name '@WorklistIds' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use aliases when you are joing to table variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetSomeData] (
@WorklistIds WorklistTable readonly
)
RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN
    (   
    select WorklistId, wlu.UserId
    from @WorklistIds t
    join [dbo].[WorklistUser] wlu on wlu.WorklistId = t.worklistId   
    -- the rest is omitted 
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly use the `@Table` name when referencing a column within a table variable.  You either need to alias the table or wrap it in square brackets:

```
select WorklistId, wlu.UserId
from @WorklistIds As W
join [dbo].[WorklistUser] wlu on wlu.WorklistId = W.worklistId
```

Or

```
select WorklistId, wlu.UserId
from @WorklistIds
join [dbo].[WorklistUser] wlu on wlu.WorklistId = [@WorklistIds].worklistId
```